# CI with emberjs

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, ember.js, integration-testing, travis-ci

I am currently researching ways to integrate a testsuite for an application based on ember.js into travis-ci. So first off, we're not on the open-source service, we use it for private repositories, etc..

I looked at how several open-source projects run their ember.js test suite and it looks like they set up a server with their project which probably gets updated whenever someone pushes to the repository. [Then PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) is used to run the tests on that server (and actually not on travis-ci itself).

The problem I have with this approach is that this adds another step (and ultimately complexity): I have to update and maintain a server with the latest code so I can use PhantomJS to run the test suite.

Another drawback is that I don't see how it would enable us to test PRs (pull-requests) either. The server would have to be updated with code from the PR. Testing PRs before they are merge is one of the great things about travis-ci.

I couldn't find much/anything about running ember.js tests only through the CLI – I am hoping someone tackled this issue before me.

Answer (score 5):

I can't speak to your questions about travis-ci ... but I can offer some thoughts about unit testing ember.js code with jasmine.

Before I started using ember.js I was unit testing with jasmine and a simple node.js module called jasmine-node. This allowed me to quickly run a suite of jasmine unit tests from the command line without having to open a browser or hack around with "js-test runner" / etc

That worked great when I had jasmine, jquery and simple javascript modules I used to keep my javascript code human readable. But the moment I needed to use ember/handlebars/etc the jasmine-node module fell down because it expects you have everything available on both global and window. But because ember is just a browser library not everything was on "global"

I started looking at PhantomJS and like yourself couldn't see myself adding the complexity. So instead of hacking around this I decided to take a weekend and write what was missing from the jasmine test runner space. I wanted the same power of jasmine-node (meaning all I would need on my CI box was a recent version of node.js and a simple npm module to run the tests)

I wrote a npm module called [jasmine-phantom-node](https://github.com/toranb/jasmine-phantom-node) and at the core it's using node.js to run phantomJS => that in turn fires up a regular jasmine html runner and scrapes the page for test results using a very basic express web app.

I spent the time to put 2 different examples in the github project so others could see how it works quickly. It's opinionated so you will need an html file in your project root that will be used by the plugin to execute your tests. It also requires jasmine, and jasmine-html along with a recent jQuery.

It solved this issue for me personally and now I can write tests against ember using simple jasmine and run it from the cmd line without a browser.

Here is a sample jasmine unit test that I wrote against an ember view recently while spiking around with this test runner. [Here](https://github.com/toranb/ember-django-rest) is a link to the full ember / django project if you want to see how the view under test is used in the app.

```
require('static/script/vendor/filtersortpage.js');
require('static/script/app/person.js');

describe ("PersonApp.PersonView Tests", function(){

  var sut, router, controller;

  beforeEach(function(){
    sut = PersonApp.PersonView.create();
    router = new Object({send:function(){}});
    controller = PersonApp.PersonController.create({});
    controller.set("target", router);
    sut.set("controller", controller);
  });

  it ("does not invoke send on router when username does not exist", function(){
    var event = {'context': {'username':'', 'set': function(){}}};
    var sendSpy = spyOn(router, 'send');
    sut.addPerson(event);
    expect(sendSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith('addPerson', jasmine.any(String));
  });

  it ("invokes send on router with username when exists", function(){
    var event = {'context': {'username':'foo', 'set': function(){}}};
    var sendSpy = spyOn(router, 'send');
    sut.addPerson(event);
    expect(sendSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('addPerson', 'foo');
  });

  it ("does not invoke set context when username does not exist", function(){
    var event = {'context': {'username':'', 'set': function(){}}};
    var setSpy = spyOn(event.context, 'set');
    sut.addPerson(event);
    expect(setSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith('username', jasmine.any(String));
  });

  it ("invokes set context to empty string when username exists", function(){
    var event = {'context': {'username':'foo', 'set': function(){}}};
    var setSpy = spyOn(event.context, 'set');
    sut.addPerson(event);
    expect(setSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('username', '');
  });
});
```

Here is the production ember view that I'm unit testing above

```
PersonApp.PersonView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'person',
  addPerson: function(event) {
    var username = event.context.username;
    if (username) {
      this.get('controller.target').send('addPerson', username);
      event.context.set('username', '');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this – I didn't dig into the code, but what what exactly does it scrape from? When phantomjs was involved, it looked like people used an external host which they had to update as well. I wanted to avoid that.

We setup a full-blown test environment with jstestrunner etc. the other week. I've been meaning to blog about it and post on here. But let me know what you did.

Comment: No external host needed :D -each time the suite runs I create a node.js express web app that hosts the single html file required to use the npm module. This file uses jasmine and jasmine-html to run your tests just like you would manually on OSX/Ubuntu -you could even look at them in the browser yourself if you commend out the line "process.exit(code=0);" in the javascript itself (I do this for local testing if I need to see a full stacktrace as PhantomJS doesn't bring back enough of the html just yet to scrape that with my npm module).

Comment: once the express web app is up with the jasmine-html page showing the test results, I use phantomJS to scrape the results from the html (via phantomjs-node) and look to see if the tests passed or failed. It also works in a fail-fast hybrid mode today because it still runs them all but only shows the first failure (again -opinionated but it helps me focus on the first test that failed)